# Function that is onto and continous

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Can there be a continuous onto function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$?

I know if a function existed it would map reals to the irrationals.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The continuous image of a connected set is connected, so $f(\Bbb R)$ has to be a connected subset of $\Bbb R - \Bbb Q$, but the latter is totally disconnected, only having points as connected subsets. So such a map could not be continuous and surjective.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Intermediate value theorem.